# Postfix - connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused)

Tags: linux, debian, postfix-mta

I have a recurring problem with postfix (on Debian Squeeze, amavisd-new and fail2ban are also installed) : All of a sudden, often at night (but not always), mail stop being delivered and the queue fulls up. Log shows a bunch of entries of this style :

```
May 18 19:54:16 ks4000003 postfix/error[6889]: 376352016039: to=<info@xxxxxxx>, relay=none, delay=0.62, delays=0.58/0.01/0/0.04, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused)
```

Once I reboot the server, it then works (and the queue is all cleared). It remains without any problem until the next time (usally once every 1-2 weeks but recently every morning I have to reboot the server).

Any idea on this would be very appreciated. I should mention I'm really a newbie in server management; I searched for similar problems on google/stackoverflow and couldn't find a real similar one.

My postfix conf :

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
always_add_missing_headers = yes
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 0
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
mydestination = ks4000003.ip-198-245-60.net, localhost, localhost.localdomain
myhostname = ks4000003.ip-198-245-60.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
nested_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/nested_header_checks
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf
relay_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relayrecipientmaps.cf
relayhost = 
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = 5
smtp_destination_rate_delay = 1s
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_client_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_client.cf
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 0
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/rbl_whitelist, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_recipient.cf, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unverified_sender, reject_unauth_destination,reject_unlisted_recipient, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client truncate.gbudb.net
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf reject_non_fqdn_sender reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_domains = 
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

Comment: Check the error log of your postfix. /var/log/mail or so ;-). You sender process could not connect to the postfix service. Perhaps the error logs tell you why.

Comment: The error I wrote is from the mail log... I have seen a strange error in the log about postfix not being able to connect to mysql briefly, but I'm not sure it's related. The websites were still working well afterwards...

Comment: I had overseen that the problem is based on connecting to port 10024. A look in the postfix config, Ah the amavis content filter. I looks like your amavis process hangs up or at least accepts no more connections. I don't know where to find the amavis logs. Possibly in the mail log too.  http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=170210

Comment: I have a amavisd-new failure (that I can't understand though) and database failure .... weird... here is an excerpt of it : http://pastebin.com/rZ5rAHQS

Comment: A friend suggested that I inspect /etc/init.d/.depend.start  targets, and when the problem will occur again, I reinit every service one by one, testing if the mail server starts acting OK between each restart, in ordre to identify which service is causing this trouble (if it's not directly amavisd-new).

Comment: EDIT : Recently, I had 2 hard drive failures, which may be related to that (I had "disk" in yellow in Munin since a long time). Anyway, if anybody encounters such random connection problems, I strongly advise that you install "Monit" on your server, with a configuration especially for Amavis. It will try to connect regularly and if it fails, it will restart the service by itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First to the amavis problem:
According to you pastebin: qmgr requests something from amavis and gets a response it does not understand. I assume that qmgr send a mail to amavis that should be checked. Either amavis is down or the mail causes amavis to produce a corrupt response. But how can you check this?

The best method is to stop the amavis service and start it from a console with

```
# amavisd debug
```

Then amavis will output to the console. 
Here is a link that might help: http://www.amavis.org/#faq

Then the database issues:

According to your pastebin: dovecot and postfix try to connect to the mysql database. postfix uses a tcp socket with the adress localhost or 127.0.0.1, dovecot uses a unix socket. If you did not change the configuration for the mysql port there should be a listening socket at the address 127.0.0.1:3306.
It is possible that the listening adress is an IPv6 address like ::1:3306

you can verify that with: `netstat -ltn`

If you configered a different port, this port must be shown in the netstat ouput. You might have configured your mysql to your outgoing ip address. Then you find something like 198.245.60.7:3306. Access to 127.0.0.1:3306 will not work in this case.

The "postfix" error message says that there is no listener at that port or you don't have access.
The "dovecot" message says you provided none or a wrong password to the mysql server, so it does not authenticate dovecot. Please check the configurations.

Comment: ok so I guess the porte gets closed for some reason. Thank you for your very helpful answer. As it includes many hints to help solving this problem, I marked it as accepted answer. I will follow up here if I find something useful.

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to know your findings. By the way: If you bound mysql to an external adresse you should reassign it to localhost. If your firewall does not block the resp. port, even script kiddys can enter your database.

Comment: Sorry, I should have to warn you not to post your netstat output. A hacker can use it to attack your services. For example (s)he will see, that there are four networkcards and there adresses and the open dns Port. Please delete it from pastebin if possible, By the way The output seems ok for me. And yes I think that your question should not be downvoted. Therefore +1

Comment: Thank you very much :)   and I guess I was stupid making the output public :/  anything I can do in addition to this to avoid an attack?

Comment: I could warn you because I made these mistakes myself and learnd from it. I do not think we are stupid. You only learn from your mistakes. Like Jeri said "fail and fail often". https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhQ7d3BK3KQ (I love that woman; She's got an electron miscroscop in the cellar. ;-) )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78519/discussion-between-guylabbe-ca-and-peter-paul-kiefer).

Comment: I see nothing strange. I think the pastebin content is the start log of amavis. There's a timestamp 7:15. Did you start amavis/the server that tiime? What i notice is that amavis is missing some scanner for content that might be in incomming mails. 7z or doc for example. There is only a litte chance, but this could cause a Perl Module used by amavis to struggle. I see no chance to find the error, if you don't have an error log. amavis logs to the mail log by default.

Comment: Another idea is to make sure that the amavis is up and send mails each attached with another mime-type content.  I would try all extensions that are listed in your pastbin. .gz .tar .tnf .doc .... Try also attachements with some extensions but different content like file.gz but with a jpeg content. Perhaps amavis crashes on such a mail. Then start amavis and try the combination again. If it will crash again you found the cause.   You see the possibillities for error are endless. Perhaps you ask the amavis guys how to find the error. I do not know amavis good enogh to help.

Comment: Thanks, That is a good idea, I will try that!! Didn't know it could crash amavis. Yes at 7:15 I started the service. I'll get back to you once I tried it

Comment: Only error logged I have are : « lost connection with 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] while sending end of data -- message may be sent more than once » from amavis and « warning: transport amavis failure -- see a previous warning/fatal/panic logfile record for the problem description » from postfix

I tried sending the attached files, didn't cause amavis to crash

the fact that MySQL seems to crash too is maybe linked. I'm starting to think I should write a script that reads the mail log and reads this error, it restarts amavis. What do you think? Anyway, I updated all packages, it may help...

Comment: I think -if mySQL crashes too- restarting amavis alone will not work. But you can try to restart mySQL alone after a crash to see if mySQL caused the error. To be sure that the mySQL crash is not only a symptom of the amavis crash, you could restart amavis only which would also verify my first assumption in this comment.

Comment: If I restart amavis alone, it starts working OK again. But often, these MySQL errors occur at the beginning and then MySQL starts working OK after a while, and amavis is still crashed. Often, I notice the problem in the morning and it has crashed during the night.

Comment: I have a debug report slightly different this time : http://pastebin.com/qpQPNRBH

Comment: ClamAV (a virus scanner) tries to open a unix socket. A unix socket is file system based and local to your server. You can check it by `ls -l /var/run/clamav`. Verify that the user that is assigned to the socket/file  clamd.ctl matches the user of the process that tries to open the port. That should be user 'amavis' or 'clamav' if clamd is started in an own user environment.

Comment: I somehow found a workaround for this problem. It's not exactly solved but I installed Monit which restart my services when it fails. Amavisd/Postfix fails everymorning, don't know why, but Monit keeps it from staying down (may be down for 1-2 minutes or less I guess) so it's already something...

Comment: With Monit running, amavis often stop running with the following error : connection failed to localhost:10024 [SMTP via TCP]

Comment: It could have been low memory issue or perrmissions issue like on next example: https://forum.howtoforge.com/threads/127-0-0-1-127-0-0-1-10024-connection-refused.39453/
As per https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mail/server/amavis-spamassassin-clamav/ amavis uses clamav for virus checking and spamassassin (if installed) for spam checking. In case clamav or spamassassin having issue then amavis will refuse connections: Postfix - connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused)